# Filter xml datetime attribute with xpath PHP

Tags: php, xml, date, datetime, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve only certain values of a xml based on an attribute. I want to iterate through all the values and only get a specific one based on "minute".

This is the xml that I'm working with:

**XML**

```
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 0:10:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,48" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="179" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 0:20:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,3" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="180" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 0:30:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,18" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="180" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 0:40:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="184" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 0:50:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="2,53" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="184" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 1:00:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,14" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="181" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 1:10:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,46" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="185" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 1:20:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,51" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="184" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 1:30:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="3,23" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="185" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 1:40:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="2,43" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="206" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
<Valores Data="30/03/2016 1:50:00">
<Medida ID="81" Variable="Velocidade do Vento" Unidades="m/s" Valor="2,46" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="82" Variable="Dirección do Vento" Unidades="Graos" Valor="205" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
<Medida ID="10001" Variable="Chuvia" Unidades="L/m2" Valor="0" Codigo_validacion="1"/>
</Valores>
```

With this php code I can iterate through all the elements and retrieve the data I want:

**PHP CODE**

```
foreach ($mypix->Valores as $valores):
    foreach ($valores as $pixinfo):
        if ($pixinfo['ID'] == VIENTO && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
            $vel_viento = $pixinfo['Valor'];
        }
        if ($pixinfo['ID'] == DIR_VIENTO && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
            $dir_viento = $pixinfo['Valor'];
        }
        if ($pixinfo['ID'] == LLUVIA && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
            $lluvia = $pixinfo['Valor'];
        }
    endforeach;
    echo "v_viento: " . $vel_viento . " d_viento: " . $dir_viento . " lluvia: " . $lluvia . "<br>";
endforeach;
```

With this my output is perfectly fine, but it retrieves all values:

**OUTPUT**

```
v_viento: 3,48 d_viento: 179 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3,3 d_viento: 180 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3,18 d_viento: 180 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3 d_viento: 184 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 2,53 d_viento: 184 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3,14 d_viento: 181 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3,46 d_viento: 185 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3,51 d_viento: 184 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 3,23 d_viento: 185 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 2,43 d_viento: 206 lluvia: 0
v_viento: 2,46 d_viento: 205 lluvia: 0
```

But I want to do now is filter and only get those values on half an hour. I just want to output the values on **30/03/2016 *:30:00**

I've been trying with multiples approaches but none convinced me enough, I've seen the xpath function but can't imagine how can I accomplish this using that function, also if there is another way around I'll be happy to try.

Thank you so much

**----------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

With this workaround I've made what I want, but I want to know if there is a xpath possibility for this.

```
foreach ($mypix->Valores as $valores):
    $fecha1 = $valores['Data'];
    if (date('i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fecha1))) == '30:00') {
        foreach ($valores as $pixinfo):
            if ($pixinfo['ID'] == VIENTO && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
                $vel_viento = $pixinfo['Valor'];
            }
            if ($pixinfo['ID'] == DIR_VIENTO && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
                $dir_viento = $pixinfo['Valor'];
            }
            if ($pixinfo['ID'] == LLUVIA && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
                $lluvia = $pixinfo['Valor'];
            }
        endforeach;
        echo "v_viento: " . $vel_viento . " d_viento: " . $dir_viento . " lluvia: " . $lluvia . "<br>";
    }
endforeach;
```

**ANSWER**

I will provide the complete answer thanks to the solution provided by @fusion3k

```
$filtered = $mypix->xpath('//Valores[contains(@Data,":30:00")]');
foreach ($filtered as $valores):
    foreach ($valores as $pixinfo):
        if ($pixinfo['ID'] == VIENTO && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
            $vel_viento = $pixinfo['Valor'];
        }
        if ($pixinfo['ID'] == DIR_VIENTO && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
            $dir_viento = $pixinfo['Valor'];
        }
        if ($pixinfo['ID'] == LLUVIA && $pixinfo['Codigo_validacion'] == COD_VAL) {
            $lluvia = $pixinfo['Valor'];
        }
    endforeach;
    echo "v_viento: " . $vel_viento . " d_viento: " . $dir_viento . " lluvia: " . $lluvia . "<br>";
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`XPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) instead of iterate through all `<Valores>`:

```
$filtered = $mypix->xpath( '//Valores[contains(@Data,":30:00")]' );

foreach( $filtered as $valores ):
(...)
endforeach;
```

Above XPath is self-explanatory: it search for `<Valores>` nodes with class “data” that contains substring “:30:00”.

---

- Read more about [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)
- Read more about [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)